# Insert array of text into last row

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, row

For the life of me I cannot figure this out. I have a summary spreadsheet that is compiled based on multiple other sheets within the same workbook. On the main sheet I find the last row and need to insert row with text but cannot. Getting stuck. I'm using an array as these fields will never change. But only the first value of the array is displaying and not the rest.

Here's my code:

```
 sub Headers()

    Dim last_row As Long 
    Dim Header() As Variant
    Header = VBA.Array("koko", "momo", "dodo", "gogo")

    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(last_row, "A").Value = Header

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSJXM.png)

Comment: From the description and picture you've provided I can't tell what you are trying to do... Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to resize the target range to get the full array contents

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(last_row, "A").Resize(1, UBound(Header) + 1).Value = Header
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

To put the array in several columns within one row simply resize the target. Remember that arrays are zero-based by default.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(last_row, "A").Resize(1, Ubound(header)+1).Value = Header
```

To put the array in several rows within one column resize the target and transpose the array.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(last_row, "A").Resize(Ubound(header)+1, 1).Value = application.transpose(Header)
```

To put the array into a single cell, Join the array.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(last_row, "A").Value = Join(Header, ", ")
```

Comment: absolutely love it. thank you so much , exactly what i needed